# Catching focus on a jQueryUI menu item with a listener broader than a click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've defined a jQueryUI menu with id `leftmenu` and on its list elements, I have defined a function on clicking one item, as follows:

```
$('#leftmenu>li').click(function () {
    var clickedId = this.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "/Session/Index/",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.length > 0)
            {

                performListItemAction(clickedId);
            }
            else
            {

                window.location.href = '/Home/Index/'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine, but now I want to change it so that instead of the `click` on the menu item, I want to capture focus and selection on that item in a more general way, such as using the keyboard. Currently, I can navigate through the menu using the up and down keys on the keyboard, but the inner code does not get called. I know this is because it is only supposed to happen on `click`, but the same thing happpened when I tried `activate` and `focus` in place of the `click` as well.

How can I get it to perform the same behavior as `click` in a more general way that captures selection and enter of the menu item?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try adding an event for `keydown()` and check to see if the enter key was pressed..

Comment: @Pamblam I just tried `$('#leftmenu>li').keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('you pressed enter ^_^');
    }...` and it didn't work

Comment: use `$(document).on("keydown", function(){  })` and check `document.activeelement` to see if it's one of the menu items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done in the `select` event. This way it catches both `click` or `select` from focused keyboard actions.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/v671x6ns/

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('#leftmenu').menu({
    select: function(e, ui) {
      var selectId = ui.item.attr("id");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "/Session/Index/",
        success: function(result) {
          if (result.length > 0) {
            performListItemAction(selectId);
          } else {
            window.location.href = '/Home/Index/'
          }
        }
      });
      console.log(e.type + " event, ID: " + selectId);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This works almost 100%. When I press Enter on an already selected menu item, it get an error `Unable to get property 'is' of undefined or null reference` but otherwise it is working well.

Comment: That's weird. Don't think anything in my code is doing that. What are the other options you are using for menu? What other scripts are running alongside this code?

Comment: `select` is the only option I am using. I am running a script `performListItemAction` that, among other things, changes the background color of the selected menu item to a specific color. Also, this problem doesn't happen with mouse clicks on already selected items, only the keyboard enter.

Comment: I do not know what `performListItemAction()` does since it is not shown in your example. I went through and created an AJAX enabled test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/v671x6ns/2/ and I could not replicate the results. Not sure how you get an already selected item.

Comment: I think there might be a typo in your code, `is` is not an attribute. `id` is. I wonder if you mistype the attribute name.

Comment: Using the debugger, I saw that the error is originating from the jqueryUI source javascript file, specifically: `_activate: function( event ) {
  if ( !this.active.is( ".ui-state-disabled" ) ) {
   if ( this.active.is( "[aria-haspopup='true']" ) ) {
    this.expand( event );
   } else {
    this.select( event );
   }
  }
 }` This is where the "is" is coming from I am pretty sure, and in Firefox, when I highlight a menu item, press enter, then press enter again without doing anything else, in the console, I see an error `this.active is null`

Comment: I will accept the answer, because I only see the error in the debugger, not during regular use of the application. Maybe it is a bug within jQueryUI.

Comment: @ITWorker could you describe the version of jQuery and jQuery UI that you are using? If you want to investigate it further, maybe pastebin your whole code?

Comment: jquery-2.2.4 and jquery-ui-1.11.4, but I'm ok with just leaving it as it is at this point. There are a lot of script files I am using so the effort isn't worth it.